# System Exception in Process.start()?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am getting a sstem Exception while executing the below lines of code.

```
Process objProcess = Process.Start(objProcessStartInfo);
//objProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Background: I am trying to execute a batch file in an upgrade installer (Custom Actions).

The above piece of code works fine in both Windows XP and Windows 7 in a sample application. however the same code inside upgrader works fine in WindowsXP - Eng & Jap, Windows 7 - Jap....but where as it is not working in Windows 7 Eng. The Process.start() method returns FALSE.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide full Exception message?

Comment: So, what exception are you getting?

Comment: Then I'd have to suggest you look to the Win 7 Eng environment rather than approach this as a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're describing many different environments, the most likely explanation is that in the failing environment, the program you're trying to start isn't being found. It could just be a path issue, or the program or something it depends on isn't installed. Can you start the program in some other way on the machine where your code is failing?